# Dart Function always returns a Future

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, future

I build a repository to get data from firestore and return it as a list of objects called `Keekzs`.

The required aim is to have a `Future<KtList<Keekz>>` returned, however I am stuck at the point that for whatever reason I am always getting `Future<KtList<Future<Keekz>>>` to be returned.
I isolated most of the inner parts and prefix it with an await expression wherever possible, but nothing changes.

Does anyone have an idea?

Here is my code:

```
final keekzs = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(Paths.keekzsToplevelCollection).get().then(
          (keekzsSnap) async => keekzsSnap.docs.map((keekzDoc) async {
            final keekzDocData = keekzDoc.data();
            final cardData = await keekzDoc.reference
                .collection(Paths.keekzCardsSublevelcollection)
                .get()
                .then(
                  (snapshotCards) async => snapshotCards.docs,
                );
            keekzDocData.addAll({
             "keekzCards": Map.fromEntries(
                cardData.map(
                  (cardDataDoc) => MapEntry(cardDataDoc.id, cardDataDoc.data()),
                ),
              )
            });
            return keekzDocData;
          }).map((keekzMapFuture) async {
            final keekzDTO = await keekzMapFuture.then(
              (keekzMap) => KeekzDto.fromFirestoreData(
                keekzMap,
                keekzMap['keekzId'].toString(),
              ).toDomain(),
            );
            return keekzDTO;
          }).toImmutableList(),
        );
 return keekzs;
```

Comment: Calling `.map` with an `async` callback will return an `Iterable` of `Future`s.  You can use `Future.wait` to obtain a `List<T>` from an `Iterable<Future<T>>`.  Also, don't mix `await` and `Future.then`; it makes your code much harder to read.

Comment: Oh thank you sou much I was not aware of Future.wait, I assumed that the await keyword is doing exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @jamesdlin mentioned in the comment :

> Calling `.map()` with an `async` callback will return an `Iterable` of `Futures`. You can use `Future.wait` to obtain a `List<T>` from an `Iterable<Future<T>>`.

If you observe your `map` function returning `Future<Keekz>` instead of `Keekz` because you are awaiting your result and that leads to `Future<List<Future<Keekz>>>` instead of the desired `Future<List<Keekz>>`.

Instead of `async await` you can use `Future.wait` to await all the futures returned by the `map` function and then convert the resulting list of `Keekz` objects into an immutable list with the help of `toImmutableList()`

The updated code may look something like :

```js
final keekzsSnap = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection(Paths.keekzsToplevelCollection)
    .get();
final keekzFutures = keekzsSnap.docs.map((keekzDoc) async {
  final keekzDocData = keekzDoc.data();
  final cardDataSnap = await keekzDoc.reference
      .collection(Paths.keekzCardsSublevelcollection)
      .get();
  final cardData = cardDataSnap.docs;
  keekzDocData.addAll({
    "keekzCards": Map.fromEntries(
      cardData.map(
        (cardDataDoc) => MapEntry(cardDataDoc.id, cardDataDoc.data()),
      ),
    ),
  });
  return keekzDocData;
});

final keekzDTOFutures = await Future.wait(keekzFutures);
final keekzs = keekzDTOFutures.map((keekzMap) =>
    KeekzDto.fromFirestoreData(
      keekzMap,
      keekzMap['keekzId'].toString(),
    ).toDomain()).toImmutableList();

return keekzs;
```

Here I have separated the fetching of `keekzsSnap` and mapping logic to get simplicity. By using `Future.wait()` we have awaited all the futures returned by mapping logic and stored in the `keekzDTOFutures` variable.

Finally, we map over `keekzDTOFutures` to convert each `keekzMap` into a `Keekz` object, and convert the resulting list into an immutable list using `toImmutableList()`.

Reference : [**wait static method**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/Future/wait.html)